# find the height of the tree and its distance from the point of observation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

From a point 5 meter above the water surface the angle of elevation of the top of a certain tree is 40 degree 10 minutes while the angle of depression of its image is 63 degree 20 minutes. Find the height of the tree and its distance from the point of observation

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the horizontal distance and $y$ be the height of the tree above the water. Then the tree top is a distance of $y-5$ above the view point, so we get the equation
$$\tan (40°10')=\frac{y-5}x$$
The image is a distance of $y+5$ below the viewpoint, so we get
$$\tan(63°20')=\frac{y+5}x$$
Solving these two equations in two variables, we get
$$x=\frac{10}{\tan(63°20')-\tan (40°10')} \approx 8.72$$
and
$$y=x \tan (40°10')+5 \approx 12.36$$